# Telnet client for Termux

Tags: telnet

I'm looking for a telnet client (for browsing telnet-based websites, such as existed before the modern Internet) for [Termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) (not for Ubuntu on Termux). Termux is a Linux command-line operating system for use on top of Android.

The closest thing I've found is Tintin++, which is a MUD client (MUDs connect over telnet), but it seems to require me to enter a name (not just the server and port), every time, and I don't want that.

A Python, Lua, Ruby, or Perl telnet client would probably be fine, since Termux has access to those (I don't mean a telnet library, I mean a finished client).

If it's a compiled program, it needs to be compiled for arm processors.